# Setting 32nd bit for Java long type yields -1

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am using Java's primitive long data type to store a flag. long has 8 bytes so 64 bit with high order bit representing the sign bit so we have 63 usable bit as a flag. 
Everything works until I turn on 32nd bit yields -1. Why is this happening?

Edit: Basically I am trying to flag the availability in an hour for first 60 bit (1 bit representing a minutes in an hour) on long data type. Let's assume start time is 0:0:00. Everything works if the end time is up to 0:30:00 but fails with 0:31:00 up to 60 minutes, meaning when I attempt to (value & (1 << 31)) for some value initialized to 0 this will not return 2^31 rather it returns -1.

Edit: Declaring a mask as 1L rather than 1 solved the problem.

Comment: Can you show what operation is returning -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should paste your code, but my guess is that you've got an "int" somewhere in your math, and that's getting turned into -1 before it gets cast to a long.

Comment: Nope, I never cast to int... but could there be an implicit casting in my code snippet?

Comment: You were right! I had to declare mask as 1L rather than 1. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is your bug:

```
(1 << mIndex)
```

That is performing a shift on a `1` which is an `int`.  If you perform a shift on an `int`, the result will be an `int`, even if the 2nd operand is greater than 32.

Try this instead:

```
(1L << mIndex)
```

Answer (score -1):

Agreed with Lawrence Kesteloot, but if you still have no luck this may be a bug in your JVM implementation. You may also have better luck using the `java.util.BitSet` class.

Comment: It seems silly to suggest a bug in the JVM without even seeing the OP's code

Comment: @HunterMcMillen that is why I said 'Agreed with Lawrence ... but if you still have no luck ...' - also have a google about the various JVM's available and check out their bug lists.

Comment: I think Hunter is saying that it is silly to suggest it ... even you think it is unlikely ... on the basis that it is likely to send the OP down the wrong track.  It is 99.9999% likely that it is not a JVM bug.